# Verilog : Use of 'PARAMETER during instantiation

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl, hardware

I am trying to understand a piece of Verilog code as below:

```
module_name instance_name (
.....
.signal1(signal1_local['SIGNAL_WIDTH - 1 : 0]),
....
);
```

I am not able to understand the 'SIGNAL_WIDTH , why is the apostrophe (') used here? Can anyone please tell what does it signify?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It's a definition. Look up `define.

Answer (score 1):

It is a tick define:

Some where in the code there will be some thing similar to:

```
'define SIGNAL_WIDTH 10
```

They tend to be global, so it could be anywhere.

Comment: Morgan is correct.  It's done this way because the code was written such that the signal: signal1 could change in ONE spot (at the `define location) and it would change the width of the signal in the rest of the code.  It's good practice.